# Как открыть порт для HFS сервера?

Tags: tcp, port

Пытаюсь создать свой HFS сервер. С пк или телефона поключённого WIFI на сервер можно зайти. С другого IP - пишет что сайт недоступен.Как я понял,проблема в портах. Используя какой-то софт из интернета я открыл порты 80 и 100(пытался использовать оба,не работает ни один). В кабинете роутера прописано -
Открытые порты по UPnP
192.168.23.177 Провайдер tcp/80 → 80 
192.168.23.177 Провайдер tcp/100 → 100
В программе для создания сервера указан IP 192.168.23.177, ссылка на сервер - http://192.168.23.177:100/. 
В брандмауэре разрешены входящие и исходящие подключения для программы. В чем может быть проблема? В портах? Если да,то как их открыть?
IP Динамический если что

Comment: Адреса, начинающиеся на 192.168, предназначены для локальных сетей и будут работать только в локальных сетях

Comment: @andreymal А что нужно сделать что бы доступ к серверу был и у других пользователей?Вне локальной сети

Comment: Получить внешний IP-адрес у вашего интернет-провайдера